# How do I resolve an SRV record in Python?

Tags: python, networking, dns, srv

Something which doesn't rely on native libraries would be better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try the dnspython library:

- http://www.dnspython.org/examples.html
- http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.7.1/html/dns.rdtypes.IN.SRV.SRV-class.html

Comment: Works thanks!           import dns.resolver

answers = dns.resolver.query('_xmpp-server._tcp.gmail.com', 'SRV')
for rdata in answers:
    print str(rdata)

Comment: This is a link only answer

Answer (score 9):

Using [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/):

```
>>> import dns.resolver
>>> domain='jabberzac.org'
>>> srvInfo = {}
>>> srv_records=dns.resolver.query('_xmpp-client._tcp.'+domain, 'SRV')
>>> for srv in srv_records:
...     srvInfo['weight']   = srv.weight
...     srvInfo['host']     = str(srv.target).rstrip('.')
...     srvInfo['priority'] = srv.priority
...     srvInfo['port']     = srv.port
... 
>>> print srvInfo
{'priority': 0, 'host': 'xmpp.jabberzac.org', 'port': 5222, 'weight': 0}
```

Answer (score 7):

[twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) has an excellent pure-python implementation, see [twisted.names](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/names) sources (especially [dns.py](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/names/dns.py)). If you can't use all of their code, maybe you can extract and repurpose their `Record_SRV` class from that file.

Comment: Links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

Using [pydns](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydns/):

```
import DNS
DNS.ParseResolvConf()
srv_req = DNS.Request(qtype = 'srv')
srv_result = srv_req.req('_ldap._tcp.example.org')

for result in srv_result.answers:
    if result['typename'] == 'SRV':
        print result['data']
```