# Persistent DNS caching not utilized by Python's socket.getaddrinfo/mercurial

Tags: python, sockets, caching, mercurial, dns

I used to have very slow DNS lookups on my Ubuntu machine when connecting through one Modem/ISP. I followed instructions (such as those [here](http://aacable.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/ubuntu-persistent-dns-caching-with-pdnsd/)) to use persistent DNS caching so I don't do repeated DNS look ups, and everything became much faster. However, I noticed that when pulling/pushing repos on mercurial, it was painfully slow to even transfer very small changes. Looking deeper, I found that all the time was taken by `_socket.getaddrinfo`, i.e., DNS lookups. Why is it that even though all web browsers use the info in `/etc/pdnsd.conf` to use old dns lookups, pythons sockets do not. How can I get mercurial to use cached lookups?

**Update**

It might also be because [getaddrinfo](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.getaddrinfo) tries to get both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses, and only returns the answer after it fails to find the ipv6 address. I am not sure how to check this though, i.e., whether the delay is due to ipv6, non-persistence or both.

**Update**

It might be related to ipv6 requests, as suggested in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014534/force-python-mechanize-urllib2-to-only-use-a-requests/6319043#6319043), I will have to check that once I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this [post](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2011-July/1275893.html) on the python list, it seems if you use BIND, then python's getaddrinfo uses cached DNS lookups. After installing BIND and starting it, then repeated DNS lookups are instantaneous.

Comment: I think the email referenced has now moved to https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2011-July/607822.html

Answer (score 1):

Pythons socket.getaddrinfo() uses the OS’s getaddrinfo() (over libc). – This has nothing to do with Python *at all*. If pdns is already configured to be in the resolution-chain, then different resolution-speeds are rooted by different requests. – Look more closely at which *exact* getaddrinfo() requests are fast, which are slow.