# Connection Error while using requests to get response from google distance matrix api

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps-api-3, python-requests, google-distancematrix-api

I am trying to develop something which involves finding distance between two geo locations.

There are many such combinations of source and destination, which I am passing into google distance API in a loop.

Part of my code:

```
key_list = [****,****,....]  #google key list
base_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?'

for i in geocodes:
    for j in key_list:

        origin_part = 'origins=' + i[0] + "," + i[1]
        destination_part = '&destinations=' + i[2] + "," + i[3]
        api_url = base_url + origin_part + destination_part + key
        json_response = requests.get(api_url,timeout=10).json()
        if json_response["status"] == "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT":
            j += 1
            i -= 1
```

This is only a part of my code.

`geocodes` is a nested list containing sublists

`[[source_latitude,source_longitude,destination_latitude,destination_longitude],....]`

The code is running fine for sometime, but after some time, it is giving me an error saying that:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='maps.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=xx,xx&destinations=xx,xx&key=xxxxx 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f53350c50f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))
```

I tried using sessions too instead of requests, but the same error is coming.

**I want to know what is causing this issue?**

And how can I rectify it, better without using `try-catch`.

Comment: How many destinations/sources? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue

Comment: @geocodezip around 1 lakh distances are to be computed, but the error comes randomly after 1000-2000 rows, it's not specific after how many distance computation the error may come.

Comment: do you have full access to google maps api? or are you just using the free version?

Comment: Check if you are in OVER_QUERY_LIMIT in the google's console.

Answer (score 1):

I think the major problem stems from the fact that the code is formatted incorrectly. The way it is setup now, I don't believe you will be able to prevent that error.

1. Nested for loops

   ```
   for i in geocodes:
       for j in key_list:
   ```

   `geocodes` is your list of lists containing origin and destination coordinates and `key_lists` contains all your api keys. The problem here is that `geocodes` is the first `for` loop. In essence, every key in your `key_list` is being used to find the distance matrix for every coordinate pair. Which is wasting api resources.
2. Usage of different api keys

   ```
   api_url = base_url + origin_part + destination_part + key
   ```

   This line of code falls within your nested `for` loops, and generates your api url. Problem here is it never changes. The last element is `key`. Since you said this was only a snippet of the code, we do not know what `key` means however, I assume that it is a static api key that was set earlier in the code. When it should actually be `j` instead, which would switch the keys.
3. Key switching on error

   ```
   if json_response["status"] == "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT":
       j+=1
       i-=1
   ```

   This line of code isn't exactly working how you think it would. It won't shift to the next `j` in the for loop, and go back an `i`. This would just add or subtract 1 from their values, and since there not `ints` or `floats` that will throw an error eventually.

Instead I suggest you change you code to this.

```
base_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?'
key_list = [****,****,....]  #google key list

index,atEnd = 0,False
for coords in geocodes:
    origin_part = 'origins=' + coords[0] + "," + coords[1]
    destination_part = '&destinations=' + coords[2] + "," + coords[3]
    api_url = base_url + origin_part + destination_part + key_list[index]
    json_response = requests.get(api_url,timeout=10).json()

    #Check if your over your daily limit, if so try the next key
    while json_response['status'] == 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT':
        index += 1
         #if all keys used to max quotas, exit
        if index == len(key_list):
            atEnd = True
            break
        api_url = base_url + origin_part + destination_part + key_list[index]
        json_response = requests.get(api_url, timeout=10).json()
    print json_response

    #Exit main loop if all quotas reached
    if atEnd == True:
        print'All of your keys quotas have been used, try again tomorrow'
        break
```

Just a note, I'm not well versed in the legal uses of the maps API. However, I am pretty sure that what you are doing violates the terms and conditions of Google, by using more than one account to  exceed your daily limit usage.

I would suggest doing the free trail on the google developers console. They supply you with 300 in credit to use their services to go beyond the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

*As already noted in other responses, your excerpt is not valid code and the use of different keys is probably abusing Google's T's & C's.  However, that is not the issue.*

#### What's the problem?

Your problem is quite clearly stated in the `requests` error.  As you can see, the error that you are hitting in urllib3 is [here](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/master/urllib3/connection.py#L148-L150).  You are not even getting to the point where you have sent any data to Google.

Looking at the specific message (`[Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution`), the system is telling you that DNS cannot resolve your hostname ("maps.googleapis.com") to an IP address.

It's a well known feature that `requests` (through `urllib3`) always calls `getaddrinfo` to resolve hostnames, so either your OS is not caching results or you have a flaky DNS server.  See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36087637/how-often-does-python-requests-perform-dns-queries) for more details.

#### What to do about it?

First option is to try a more reliable DNS server - many people use Google's [public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) when they start having such problems.

If that doesn't work, you could try doing the DNS lookup yourself (i.e. call `getaddrinfo`) and caching the IP address in your application (and then use that instead of the hostname in the URL), or you could install a DNS cache on your machine.  These won't prevent the DNS failure, but they should reduce the impact.