# How can I run nslookup in python?

Tags: python

First, I run `nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks.google.com 8.8.8.8` in bash, and get the result like this:

```
  Server:   8.8.8.8
  Address:  8.8.8.8#53

  Non-authoritative answer:
  _netblocks.google.com text = "v=spf1 ip4:64.18.0.0/20 ip4:64.233.160.0/19 ip4:66.102.0.0/20 ip4:66.249.80.0/20 ip4:72.14.192.0/18 ip4:74.125.0.0/16 ip4:108.177.8.0/21 ip4:173.194.0.0/16 ip4:207.126.144.0/20 ip4:209.85.128.0/17 ip4:216.58.192.0/19 ip4:216.239.32.0/19 ~all"

  Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

Now, I have a task to get the same result in python, and can't use `os` lib to run bash command.
Which lib can I use? And how to use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189253/how-do-i-resolve-an-srv-record-in-python explains how to do this in native Python (though with SRV instead of TXT).

Comment: @tripleee Thank you. That solved my problem. But why I was voted down...

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but if this is a duplicate, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Although you should have posted what you've already tried (as specified in the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page), here's a sample that uses [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#module-subprocess):

```
import subprocess
import shlex

command = "nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks.google.com 8.8.8.8"
p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
# if running on Windows, split for ("\r\n")
for line in out.split("\n"):
    # process the line, in our case simply print it
    print(line)
```